# ButtonID2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); seems to the appliaction

Tags: android

I have a simple app with two screen fragments.
When the used select a button in want to make one or more other buttons visible on the fragment.
I have set the buttons as invisible in the layut.
When the buttons is clicked the emulalator jumps to the Home screen.

The app is still running and if I click the overview button I can restore the app but the buttons is still not visible.

```
view.findViewById(R.id.btn1B).setOnClickListener(new view.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
    Button ButtonID2 = view.findViewById(R.id.btn1C);
    ButtonID2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Button ButtonID3 = view.findViewById(R.id.btn2C);
    ButtonID3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);        
    }
});
```

FirstFragmant.java

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, null);
        return root;
    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        view.findViewById(R.id.button_first).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                NavHostFragment.findNavController(FirstFragment.this)
                        .navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment);
            }

        });

        view.findViewById(R.id.button_Start).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {

                }
        });
        view.findViewById(R.id.btn1A).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Button ButtonID = view.findViewById(R.id.btn1A);
                String buttonText = ButtonID.getText().toString();
                
                //get the current timeStamp
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MMM:yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
                final String strDate = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
                MainActivity.gameEvent[0]= strDate;
                MainActivity.gameEvent[1] = buttonText;
                //CharSequence text = buttonText; //ButtonID.set();
                //int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                //Toast toast = Toast.makeText( getContext(), strDate + "-" + text, duration);
                //toast.show();
            }
        });
        view.findViewById(R.id.btn1B).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Button ButtonID2 = view.findViewById(R.id.btn1C);
                //ButtonID2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                ButtonID2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Button ButtonID3 = view.findViewById(R.id.btn2C);
                ButtonID3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Button ButtonID1 = view.findViewById(R.id.btn1B);
                String buttonText = ButtonID1.getText().toString();

                MainActivity.gameEvent[2] = buttonText;
                //CharSequence text = buttonText; //ButtonID.set();
                //int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                //Toast toast = Toast.makeText( getContext(), MainActivity.gameEvent[0] + "," + MainActivity.gameEvent[1] + "," + MainActivity.gameEvent[2], duration);
                //toast.show();
            }
        });
        view.findViewById(R.id.btn1C).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Button ButtonID = view.findViewById(R.id.btn1C);
                String buttonText = ButtonID.getText().toString();
                CharSequence text = buttonText; //ButtonID.set();
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                MainActivity.gameEvent[3] = buttonText;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText( getContext(), MainActivity.gameEvent[0] + "," + MainActivity.gameEvent[1] + "," + MainActivity.gameEvent[2] + "," + MainActivity.gameEvent[3], duration);
                toast.show();
                
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This being your first question, welcome to the site.

Did you set `R.id.btn1B` to be invisible in the layout as well? What you've done here is you've made `btn1C` and btn2C`to be visible ONLY AFTER you click on`btn1B`, since it's in the click listener; but if` btn1B` is also not visible, there's nothing to happen.

As a side note, if you're just learning Android now, you should start with Kotlin instead of Java, it's a much easiest experience. I would set up Kotlin, with DataBinding, and this exact same code will look like this:

```kotlin
viewBinding.btn1B.onClick {
    viewBinding.btn1C.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    viewBinding.btn2C.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

Comment: Yes in the XML layout R.id.btn1B is visible with R.id.btn1C and R.id.btn2C both being invisible. When i click R.id.btn1B i want  btn1C and btn2C to become visible.

Comment: right, so where did you put your block of code? Is it in Activity or Fragment?

Comment: The code is in FirstFragment.java .  I have added the rest of the code ive used. I was able to create and display an array of the button labels/text to but seem unable to set any of the buttons parameters i.e visibility.

Comment: In your `onCreateView`, you probably should do this instead `inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container);` (note, you had `null` for the view parent)`.

Just FYI, I would HIGHLY recommend moving to Kotlin, Java code is just too verbose and gets harder to reason about... using states in global Singletons like `MainActivity.gameEvent[0]` is REALLY bad, look at Google's LifeCycles library and learn to use `ViewModel`s, put states in there instead, via Koin if possible. Android has a steep learning curve at the start, but worth spending time learning the best way to do these things.

Answer (score 0):

Using the debugger I was able to get a better understanding of the object structure.

Button ButtonID2 = view.findViewById(R.id.btn1C); was returning a null. setting a property/attribute caused an error.

Button Btn = view.findViewById(R.id.btn1B) returned the button object within/of the OnClickListener
But Button ButtonID2 = view.findViewById(R.id.btn1C); returns a null.

I instead used getParentFragment().getView() to get the fragments view.

Button ButtonID2 = getParentFragment().getView().findViewById(R.id.btn1C);